# Given a normal distribution, how do you determine a proportion that is outside of a range?

Tags: normal-distribution

I am presented with the question:

> The fill volume of an automated filling machine used for filling cans of carbonated beverage is normally distributed with a mean of 12.4 fluid ounces and a standard deviation of 0.1 fluid ounce. Round the answers to 3 significant digits.
>
> b) If all cans less than 12.1 or greater than 12.6 ounces are scrapped, what proportion of cans is scrapped?

I was able to figure out how to get the rest of the question, but for some reason I can't seem to get this answer. Can anyone explain how I might solve this problem? BTW, I am able to use a TI 84, so an explanation using normalcdf() would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the proportion of cans that are scrapped and cans that are not scrapped is 1. These are *complementary* probabilities, because together they cover every possible scenario. A can is either within the range, or outside of it. There is no chance that a can is neither in the range nor outside of it, so the probabilities of these two situations add to 1.

You can use normalcdf to figure out the proportion of cans that are not scrapped.

```
normalcdf(12.1, 12.6, 12.4, 0.1)
```

Now you can subtract this from 1 to figure out the proportion of cans that **are** scrapped.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought... I get an answer of .0241, but the submission site says that is incorrect. Perhaps there is a problem with the website?

Comment: @rphello101 I just tried it on my TI-84 and I also got .0241. I think the submission site may have a problem unless both of us made a mistake somewhere... (edit: see below)

Comment: @rphello101 I just noticed, it says to round your answers to 3 significant digits. Have you tried .024? I know that technically, .0241 is 3 significant figures, but maybe it means 3 decimal places.

Comment: I'm glad you verified it. I'll send a message to my professor. In regards to your second comment, that's a good point, but unfortunately, I ran out of submissions...

Comment: Oh just realized the problem... This was the only answer in the entire homework set that was supposed to be entered as a %. The answer *is* .0241, but it's supposed to be represented as 2.41%... What a dumb thing to lose a point on.

Comment: @rphello101 Wow, that is annoying... at least we understand it now.